# In app purchase crash occasionally

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have in app purchase in three of my apps. The first one works fine since more than a year. In that I have this routine:

```
-(void)purchaseProUpgrade{
  SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier: inAppProductId];

  if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  else [self purchaseFailedWithError:nil];
}
```

But paymentWithProductIdentifier has been depreciated. So in the next two apps I changed this to (the rest of the code is the same):

```
-(void)purchaseProUpgrade{
 SKPayment *payment =[SKPayment paymentWithProduct: self.upgradeProduct];

   if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
   else [self purchaseFailedWithError:nil];
}
```

where "upgradeProduct" is set by

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
   NSArray *products = response.products;
   if([products count]>0)  self.upgradeProduct = products[0];

   // the user is warned if upgradeProduct not is set 
}

// upgradeProduct is declared as Strong and I am using ARC.
```

This works fine in the sandbox even when I try to provoking it by jumping back and forth to the buy view, cancel buying etc. It works if I buy my app from the app store. I also seems to work for a majority of the users since there is sales registered.

However, I am getting crash reports almost every day saying that [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment] has crashed with  'Invalid product identifier: (null)'. In some cases it seems that people have crashed, restarted the app at once and tried to buy again and crashed.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there is a sample in Github, have a look the below link

https://github.com/ebutterfly/EBPurchase

Comment: Thanks. However, it is essentially the same code that I am using.